# How to filter by ReferenceProperty in Java's GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Assuming I have the following (simplified) models in a GAE Java application:

```
Entity project = new Entity("Project")
project.setProperty("name", "test");
```

and

```
Entity task = new Entity("Task");
task.setProperty("name", "test");
task.setProperty("project", project.getKey());
```

How do I get all `Task`s that have a reference to a specific `Project`?

I've tried

```
    Query q = new Query("Task");
    Query.FilterPredicate projectFilter =
            new Query.FilterPredicate("project",
                    Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                    project.getKey()
                    );
    q.setFilter(projectFilter);
```

But to no avail.
I've check the actual data with the Datastore viewer and everything is in place.
`Task`s have a proper `Key` to a project and all of the properties are indexed.

The only thing that seems out of the ordinary, is the fact that (considering my app supports multi-tenancy), that `Project` key as a namespace prefix on the viewer.

Could that be the problem, and is there any solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `project.getKey().getId()` instead,

or use the special key filter: `Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY`

which is described here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Key_Filters